# TypeError: Whisper.forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tokens' when creating chatbot with fine-tuned model

Tags: chatbot, openai-api, transformer-model, fine-tuning, whisper

On google colab I am creating a chatbot, using whisper to transcribe an audio then generate response, based on a fine-tuned model. I use the model with pure-text chatbot first, and it works fine, but when integrating whisper, it give me the error.

load the model:

```
model.save_pretrained("/content/saved_model")
tokenizer.save_pretrained("/content/saved_tokenizer")

model_path = "/content/saved_model"
tokenizer_path = "/content/saved_tokenizer"

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_path)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(tokenizer_path)

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)
```

my function for pure-text chatbot:

```
def generate_response(input_text):
    input_ids = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids.to(device)
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(input_ids)
    predicted_label = torch.argmax(outputs.logits).item()

    # Use the original label name from the dataframe
    predicted_disease_or_symptom = df.loc[df['labels'] == predicted_label, 'label'].iloc[0]

    return predicted_disease_or_symptom 

while True:
    user_input = input("User: ")
    if user_input.lower() == "exit":
        break
    response = generate_response(user_input)
    print(f"Chatbot: {response}")
```

Until now all work well. Then I import whisper and utilize previous function:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git 

import whisper
themodel = whisper.load_model('base')

while True:
    user_input = input("User: ")
    if user_input.lower() == "exit":
        break
    if user_input.lower() == "audio":
        audio_path = input("Enter audio file path: ")
        
        # Transcribe audio using Whisper
        text = themodel.transcribe(audio_path)
        transcription = text['text']
        print("Transcribed Text:", transcription)
        
        # Generate a response using the chatbot model
        response = generate_response(transcription)
        
    else:
        response = generate_response(user_input)
    print(f"Chatbot: {response}")
```

This chatbot let me enter audio path and gave me transcribed text, but raised error when generating response:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-de822a5197f3> in <cell line: 4>()
     15 
     16         # Generate a response using the chatbot model
---> 17         response = generate_response(transcription)
     18 
     19     else:

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1499                 or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501             return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

TypeError: Whisper.forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tokens'
```

Where could be the problem? I don't think it is the problem of the function "generate_response" as it worked for the previous one, so I thought it might be the incampatibility between whisper and this function. But have no idea where to spot. Or any other substitute so that I can still do the transcribing?

Answer (score 0):

Usual this problem when try use jit trace.
I see in you log - 1502         # Do not call functions when jit is used

```
import os
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
import whisper

name = "medium"

net = whisper.load_model(name, download_root=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), ""))
net = net.eval()
x = torch.rand(1, 80, 3000)
mod = torch.jit.trace(net, x)
mod.save("medium_jit_trace.pt")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\1111111\Whisper\export\whisper_m\export.py", line 15, in <module>
    mod = torch.jit.trace(net, x)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_trace.py", line 750, in trace
    return trace_module(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_trace.py", line 967, in trace_module
    module._c._create_method_from_trace(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1118, in _slow_forward
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tokens'
```